# Filtering Table for overlapping time slots

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an sql table `mytable` that has timestamp columns indicating the row's validity, named `valid_time_from` and `valid_time_until`. Besides that, lets assume my table has a unique `major_id` and a non_unique `minor_id`. In theory, for every `minor_id`, the corresponding data-rows have non-overlapping timestamps:

Example:

| major_id | minor_id | valid_time_from | valid_time_until |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 555 | 01.01.2000 | 31.12.2000 |
| 2 | 555 | 31.12.2000 | 03.01.2001 |
| 3 | 555 | 03.01.2001 | 01.05.2010 |

In the example, the data is valid since the timestamps to the minor_id don't overlap.

However, in practice the table contains data like this as well.

| major_id | minor_id | valid_time_from | valid_time_until |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 666 | 01.01.2000 | 31.12.2000 |
| 102 | 666 | 31.12.2000 | 03.01.2001 |
| 103 | 666 | 01.01.2001 | 01.05.2010 |

In this example, for the time between 01.01.2001 and 01.03.2001 the time slots for validity overlap.

In my application, I query the table like this:

```
select * from mytable m2 where minor_id = 666 and '02.01.2001' >= m2.valid_time_from and '02.01.2001' < m2.valid_time_to
```

I assume, I get **exactly one hit** for a given timestamp and minor_id, but the corrupt data makes this impossible.

How can I dynamically preprocess `mytable` in order to remove duplicates for a given `minor_id` and timestamp (and take the row with the highest `major_id`, 103 in the example.

---

To make it even more complicated, I need to query the data via a join from another table, like

```
select * from my_other_table m2 join mytable m on m2.minor_id = m.minor_id and m2.timestamp >= m.valid_time_from and m2.timestamp < m.valid_time_until
```

I like Gordon Linoff's Solution but I dont get how to implement it in a join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use reasonable date formats.

Second.  You don't really need to preprocess the table.  You can use `distinct on` or `order by`/`limit`:

```
select m2.*
from mytable m2
where minor_id = 666 and
      '2001-02-01' >= m2.valid_time_from and
      '2001-02-01' < m2.valid_time_to
order by major_id desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Do you know how to make use of this in a join (see my edited question).

Comment: @Lokomotywa . . . You should ask another question, particularly after the original has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a food for thought pattern to search for overlaps without specifying an exact date

```
select * -- Inspect and see what you want
  from mytable m1
 inner
  join mytable m2
    on m1.minor_id = m2.minor_id
 where -- Overlap condition on arbitrary date
       m1.valid_from >= m2.valid_from
   AND m1.valid_from <= m2.valid_to
   AND -- Don't match the record itself
       NOT (m1.valid_from = m2.valid_from
       AND m1.valid_to = m2.valid_to)
```